# Android Studio - Cardview must click twice even i change android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-cardview, cardview

im sorry. im begginer on android. i jus write a code with 4 cardview and the first one must click twice to work. But, the others cardview work with 1 click :(

And 3 others cardview can work without i give focusableInTouchMode property. Im confused with this issue and i have read about button clicked twice, it doesn't for me too. Please help me :)

Would you help me?

Here it;s my code :

...

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/bangunan_menu"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bangunan"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Data Bangunan"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/penyewa_menu"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/penyewa"/>

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Data Penyewa"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

...

Thank you :)

Comment: You need to Validate double click at run time .The `OnClickListener` will give give you callback for single click only. There is no way detect double click with xml only .

Comment: ohh, crap :( it's my fault :( i put OnclickListener inside OnclickListener of this cardview :( Thank's @ADM you save my day

Comment: haha, i was going to ask about the code , it was weird, happy you solved your problem , let us know any other trouble you have :)